# Particular solution of $y'' -3y' + 2y = e^t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find a particular solution of $$y'' -3y' + 2y = e^t$$

My fundamental set is: $$y_1 = e^{2t}\\y_2 = e^t$$

So I chose $y_p = A t e^t$, which gives me:$$y_p' = Ae^t + Ate^t\\y_p'' = 2Ae^t + Ate^t$$

but when I substitute this into the equation $$y'' -3y' + 2y = te^t$$ I get $A = -t$, and I have trouble understanding what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have changed the right-hand side of the equation to $te^t$ instead of $e^t$.

Comment: Thank you, I was completely convinced you were to use the particular solution there too.

Answer (score 2):

When you substitute into the equation you have:

$2Ae^t + Ate^t -3(Ae^t + Ate^t) +2(A t e^t)=e^t \implies e^t(-3At+3At+2A-3A)=e^t $

So A=-1

Answer (score 0):

For the particular solution, try $y_p=t(c_1e^t)$ where the $t$ us given to account for the $e^t$ in the complementary solution (I will go through that if you like).